# Jssor slider problems with $SlideDuration option

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I have a problem with setting up a `$SlideDuration` option.

I am using `jsson slider` **without jQuery**.

The problem I have you can see even with the demo files which I took from the creators website.

So I am trying to setup a `$SlideDuration:5000`.

```
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $SlideDuration:5000,
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Cols: 1,
            $Align: 0,
            $NoDrag: true
          }
        };
```

As you can see [**here**](http://www.virtualnigrad.com/slidetest/no-jquery.html). I can not make it to take that option as I set it to `5000ms`. I have even try to change it directly in the code `jssor.slider.min.js` - but no luck again. It is always using it's default value `500`.

Can someone please help me with this, as I have not clue where is the problem.

Many thanks,
Branja

Answer (score 1):

Please set $Idle to 5000.

$SlideDuration is for sliding left <-> right.